# Rails form route to static URL after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a basic rails form that searches for parameters from a database. I want to track every time someone does a search (ie submits this form). My controller has 2 actions (an index where the form the located and a create with all the search stuff). Currently, when the form is submitted, it does not change the URL. The URL stays the name of the model. How do I change that in routes so that the URL will change allowing Analytics to see the number of times this page was visited?

```
  resources :prices, only: [:index, :create]
```

Thank you

Comment: What about if you write a url that you expected here?

Comment: www.whatever.com/prices to www.whatever.com/searchresults

Comment: can you tell me about what `searchresults` is like? It is  www.whatever.com/?name=test&from=US or www.whatever.com/search?name=test&from=US.

Comment: I want it clean - www.whatever.com/searchresults - I do not want the post information there.

Comment: By Analytics do you mean Google Analytics, or something else?

Comment: Yes. It seems the easiest way (I know there are others) to track is if the results display on a page with a unique URL.

Comment: Check my answer - although make sure GA doesn't "just work" doing what you are doing already

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your form display in a new action, so that the URL will update on posting.

```
resources :prices, only: [:index, :new, :create]

def index 
  redirect_to new_price_path
end

def new 
  @price = Price.new
  render "form"
end

def create
  # your search results
end
```

Something like that allows you to use standard REST verbs and still achieve what you want.

I would ask though before you go to the effort of making a change, have you tested that Analytics doesn't pick up the event on the form submission, even though the URL doesn't change? Real time analytics view can often show this.

Comment: You can use Google tags to pick up an event (like a submission), but it is really limited (for example Google will count it as a goal conversion) and is complicated to setup. The URL seems like a much more straightforward way.

Comment: yeah, I suppose that it would not give you a clean count of requests. Does the code change I suggested make sense in this case?